# При тестировании(JUnit) массива выбивает ошибку required: int[] found: int,int,int,int

Tags: java, массивы, junit

Есть тест, который должен протестировать метод `back`, который переворачивает массив, например `4, 1, 6, 2` на `2, 6, 1, 4`. При тестировании выдает ошибку:

```
cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR] required: int[]
[ERROR] found: int,int,int,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Понимаю, что проблема в синтаксисе и строка с иннициализацией массива не правильна. Как правильно передать значения в тестированный класс?

```
@Test
public void whenTurnArrayWithEvenAmountOfElementsThenTurnedArray() {
    Turn turn = new Turn();
    int[] resultArray = turn.back(4, 1, 6, 2);
    int[] expectArray = turn.back(2, 6, 1, 4);
    assertThat(resultArray, is(expectArray));
}
```

Вот сам тестируемый метод, кому было интересно.

```
public int[] back(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
            int k = array[i];
            array[i] = array[array.length - i + 1];
            array[array.length - i + 1] = k;
        }
    return array;
    }
```

Comment: Ты не знаешь как создать массив?

Comment: А можно увидеть код метода `back`?

Comment: Я для вас скинул тестируемый метод. Простите, я не подумал за него.

Comment: @ДмитрийСеров ок, дополнил ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понимаю метод `back`, то нужно передавать в метод массив одним параметров, а не числа в нескольких параметрах. Сделать это можно используя следующий синтаксис: `new int[] {0, 1, 2, ...}`. К тому же не нужно снова вызывать метод `back` для "ожидаемого" массива.

```
@Test
public void whenTurnArrayWithEvenAmountOfElementsThenTurnedArray() {
    Turn turn = new Turn();
    int[] resultArray = turn.back(new int[] {4, 1, 6, 2});
    int[] expectArray = new int[] {2, 6, 1, 4};
    assertThat(resultArray, is(expectArray));
}
```

Или же можно изменить сам метод `back`, чтобы его вызов из теста был корректен:

```
public int[] back(int... array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
        int k = array[i];
        array[i] = array[array.length - i + 1];
        array[array.length - i + 1] = k;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Тогда правильный тест будет следующим:

```
@Test
public void whenTurnArrayWithEvenAmountOfElementsThenTurnedArray() {
    Turn turn = new Turn();
    int[] resultArray = turn.back(4, 1, 6, 2);
    int[] expectArray = new int[] {2, 6, 1, 4};
    assertThat(resultArray, is(expectArray));
}
```

Comment: А как сделать тест без изменения метода "back"?

Comment: @ДмитрийСеров первый вариант теста в ответе

Comment: Ага, увидел, спасибо большое